# DataGrid Select Column

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to programatically select an entire column in a WPF DataGrid. My code seems to work but it is REALLY slow! I'm guessing it is because it is continually having to call ScrollIntoView. Can someone help me with a solution to speed it up or an alternative to select the entire column?

```
public static void SelectColumn(DataGrid grid, int column)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        // Select each cell in this column
        var cell = DataGridHelper.GetCell(grid, i, column);
        if (cell != null)
        {
            cell.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }

    DataGridHelper.GetCell(grid, 0, column).Focus();
}


public static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGrid grid, int row, int column)
{
    DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(grid, row);

    if (rowContainer != null)
    {
        DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = TreeHelper.GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
        if (presenter == null)
        {
            // may be virtualized, bring into view and try again
            grid.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, grid.Columns[column]);
            presenter = TreeHelper.GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
        }

        if (presenter != null)
        {
            // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            if (cell == null)
            {
                // may be virtualized, bring into view and try again
                grid.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, grid.Columns[column]);
                cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            }

            return cell;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public static DataGridRow GetRow(DataGrid grid, int index)
{

    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    if (row == null)
    {
        // may be virtualized, bring into view and try again
        grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[index]);
        row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
    }

    return row;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

I'm trying out the solution suggested by @ianschol. Here is what I have (I bind in code behind b/c I don't know how many columns I need until runtime):

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.CurrentData.Data[0].Length; i++)
        {
            TheGrid.Columns.Add(
                new DataGridTextColumn
                {
                    Header = (this.CurrentData.Rank > 1) ? string.Format(this.culture, headerFormatString, i + 1) : string.Empty,
                    Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}].DataValue", i)) { ValidatesOnDataErrors = true, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged },
                    Width = DataGridLength.Auto,
                    ElementStyle = new Style
                    {
                        TargetType = typeof(TextBlock),
                        Triggers = { this.errorTrigger }
                    },

                    EditingElementStyle = new Style
                    {
                        TargetType = typeof(TextBox),
                        Triggers = { this.errorTrigger }
                    },

                    CellStyle = new Style
                    {
                        TargetType = typeof(DataGridCell),
                        Setters =
                        {
                            new Setter
                            {
                                Property = DataGridCell.IsSelectedProperty,
                                Value = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}].IsSelected", i)) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged },
                            }
                        },
                    }
                });
        }
```

and my IsSelected property:

```
private bool isSelected = false;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isSelected;
        }

        set
        {
            this.isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
```

And the new SelectColumn code:

```
public static void SelectColumn(DataGrid grid, int column)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            // Select each cell in this column
            ((DataItem[])(grid.Items[i]))[column].IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that if I update the IsSelected property in code, it updates the GUI (kinda, its quirky) but not vice versa. I.e. if I select a cell/row in the GUI, it doesn't call the property setter in the code. As you can see the binding is TwoWay so I'm not sure the issue.

**Another UPDATE:** The issue definitely seems to be with virtualization. If i turn off virtualization (VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" ) it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more effective approach would probably be to have IsSelected properties on the DataSource's class, such that each column has a corresponding "IsSelected" property.

```
public class MyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            Notify("Name");
        }
    }

    private bool nameSelected = false;
    public bool NameSelected
    {
        get { return nameSelected; }
        set
        {
            nameSelected = value;
            Notify("NameSelected");
        }
    }

  //... etc ...
}
```

Next, you can alter the CellStyle for each Column to bind the cells' IsSelected property to the related IsSelected property on the class.

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="scratchGrid" CanUserAddRows="False"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionUnit="Cell">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="User Name" Width="200">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding NameSelected}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="User Age" Width="80">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding AgeSelected}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Finally, implement your select-all code like so (this does select-all on Age, you may want to make a more generic/elegant implementation ;) ) :

```
        foreach (MyData user in Users)
        {
            user.AgeSelected = true;
        }
```

You'll have to take care to make sure all your NotifyPropertyChanged behavior is lined up, since you're expecting the grid to recognize that properties inside its bound collection are being updated.

Comment: You slightly misunderstand the problem, the default selection unit is a row, if one would want to select a column one would need an IsSelected property for every property, and a different cell-style for each column which binds to it.

Comment: That's what I intended to suggest, H.B., though I'm reviewing what I wrote and my language is a bit vague.  Will revise with example.

Comment: It seems to work on from the code to the GUI but not vice versa. I.e. if i set the isselected in code it is visible in gui (kinda, its quirky). But if i so something like select a single cell or a row, it does propagate to the property in code (the setter doesn't get called). I have the binding set to TwoWay so I'm not sure the issue. I will post my new code in the question so you can see what I'm doing.

Comment: Did you try using a `BindingExpression` to inspect the binding(s)?  It sounds like there's an issue with the binding, since it's not propagating changes to the source (can't blame that on UI refresh).  By 'quirky' do you mean that the GUI doesn't always update properly?

Comment: correct, the gui doesn't always update correctly. I'm wondering if it has to do with virtualization because it gets screwy with whether it selects it or not if it is off the first "screen" (i.e. if i have to scroll down)

Comment: The issue definitely seems to be with virtualization. If i turn off virtualization (VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" ) it works fine.

Comment: Ok, got it, had to set the VirtualizationMode to Standard.